# Views: Display filters as a HTML UL list of links with clean mark up

Tags: theming, views

I have a View that has a filter which allows users to select nodes that contain specific taxonomy terms.

I would like to display this as a HTML list of links (`<ul>`). How can I do this?

---

### Steps I have tried

**1. Using Better Exposed filters**

This displays a filter as links. But the links are displayed wrapped in `<Div>` tags instead  of a `UL` tag.

**2. Using Views template**

Using `views-exposed-form.tpl.php` lets you access the exposed form, but it doesn't let you access the actual widget the makes up the filter.

**3. Using Custom Code**

[This page](http://knackforge.com/blog/suresh/drupal-views-exposed-filter-links) says you can turn a select list into links via a custom module. But it requires Javascript to make the links work, which seems bad practise to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would also go for step 3 and you really need JS for that option. Another option is, structure the links as it looks when you do a search like so..

```
// Merge the option name or key into the link
$link = "your-view?category=" . $select_option;
// Create the link
$somearrayforULlist[] = l($select_option, $link);
```

So when you click one of the links, it would reload the page and your view will use the filter values in the URL in your form.

[image]

Comment: Where would I put that code?

Comment: The same function in the link you posted in Step 3, hook_form_alter specifically targeting your View filter form.